# Does ASP have a Current event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Does ASP have a construct similar to Access's On Current event? I've inherited a set of ASP web forms coded in C# and the rules associated with the form controls kick in OK if you click one of the controls but I need them to apply when the form opens, not only on change. That they don't is allowing bad data.

Comment: _What have you tried so far?_ Show your work here.. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]. And what is `they don't is allowing bad data` mean?

Comment: You can put the rules in a dedicated function and call it in your event handlers and also on page load.

Comment: @SonerGönül: One control being set to No would disable a number of other controls, but when the form opens displaying data already stored with a No value, the other controls aren't disabled and data can be entered, hence bad data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need them to apply when the form opens, not only on change.

With ASP.NET you can use the `Page_Load` event handler; check out the [page lifecycle documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more details, as that may lead you to something more appropriate and would be a rather educational read on the whole.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the documentation and the Page_Load handler